# Providing multiple updates from python to HTML using flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to build a web-based user interface for my python program. For this I wish to  send live updates of my dataFrameFinal to the html page, but from Flask I can only send the update once each time the form is submitted.

Currently in my main.py I have the function

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():

    # gets the number of sims from the form on submit
    numSims = int(request.form['numSims'])

    dataFrameFinal = runSims(num_sims=numSims)

    return jsonify({'dataframe' : dataFrameFinal .reset_index().to_html()})
```

This will get the number of sims (numSims) when the form is submitted and return the table once all the simulations are run to the javascript file which will load the result onto the html page.

However, as I am running upwards of 10,000 sims (which can take more than 10 mins to run) I'm hoping to send live versions of the dataFrameFinal (e.g send updates to the html page every 10 sims). Would really appreciate any suggestions on how I could do this.

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm very new to this and couldn't find any other similar posts so thought I would ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a task manager.

[Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) is a widely-used option, though there are others out there.

Using celery allows you to starts an asynchronous (or background) task/process from your view function. Your view can then return a response to the user (so that the user doesn't have to wait for all the processing to be done before it sees a response).

Celery requires a message broker for starting tasks and returning results. ([More details.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#choosing-a-broker)) You can also use this broker for storing progress updates.

For example, if you're using Redis, when `runSims()` has processed 100 sims, you can store something like `processed: 100` in Redis. Then, you can write a Flask view function to read this value out of Redis and return it to the user. One option for live updating the page would be to have some Javascript on the page that calls that Flask view function every second. The Flask view function will read whatever number is currently stored in Redis (which your celery task/process should be updating), and return it to the Javascript so it can update some field on the page.

Your process function will eventually look something like this:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():

    # gets the number of sims from the form on submit
    numSims = int(request.form['numSims'])

    # Start the celery task
    runSims.apply_async(num_sims=numSims)

    # Let the user know that processing has started
    return 'Your task has started processing. Stay on the page for live updates.'
```

And your `get_progress()` function may look something like this:

```
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis()

@app.route('/progress', methods=['GET'])
def progress():
    return r.get('processed')
```